# GetNumberFormat returning junk value for Non-English Domain

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am using the `GetNumberFormat` function to get the formatted number but its returning the junk value for the Non-English locale.

Its working fine for English locale.

Code:

```
int FormatNumber(double number, long nbrDecs, char* destBuf, int bufSize)
{
char        infoBuf[3];
char        decimalSep[10];
char        thousandSep[10];
char        sourceNbr[50];
NUMBERFMT*  customFormat = NULL;
UINT        defDigits;
LCID        lcid;
int         status;

lcid = GetUserDefaultLCID();

status = GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_IDIGITS, infoBuf, 3);
if (status == 0){
    return status;
}

defDigits =  atoi(infoBuf);
if (defDigits != (UINT) nbrDecs){
    customFormat = new NUMBERFMT;

    customFormat->NumDigits = nbrDecs;

    status = GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_ILZERO, infoBuf, 3);
    customFormat->LeadingZero = atoi(infoBuf);

    status = GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_SGROUPING, infoBuf, 3);
    customFormat->Grouping = atoi(infoBuf);

    status = GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_STHOUSAND, thousandSep, 10);
    customFormat->lpThousandSep = thousandSep;

    status = GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_SDECIMAL, decimalSep, 10);
    customFormat->lpDecimalSep = decimalSep;

    status = GetLocaleInfo(lcid, LOCALE_INEGNUMBER, infoBuf, 3);
    customFormat->NegativeOrder = atoi(infoBu`enter code here`f);
}

sprintf_s(sourceNbr, sizeof(sourceNbr),"%f", number)
status = GetNumberFormat(lcid, 0, sourceNbr, customFormat, destBuf,     bufSize);
// here destBuf is having the junk value. 

if (customFormat != NULL)
    delete customFormat;

return status; 
}
```

I am getting junk value. Here `destBuf` is returning the junk value.

Comment: Check value returned by the _GetNumberFormat()_ function. If it is 0 call _GetLastError()_ to get extended error information.

Comment: The code you have posted is incomplete. It won't work at all. It is ANSI code so it may not work for some non-English languages.

Comment: Actually to make this code working properly for different languages it is necessary to turn on the multi language support by setting _Character Set_ parameter in the project configuration properties to **Use Unicode Character Set**. As well as change code to use `TCHAR` type instead of `char`.